# How can I call for a variable by the second character on its name?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list of variables like this

```
c1 = 0
c2 = 0
```

all the way up to `c9`. How can I call for the variable based on the number next to the c?

So for example lets say I want to generalize that when a variable is equal to 0 another variable with the same number next to is defined.

```
if c[n] = 0
    p[n] = 'X'
```

PS. Sorry for any formating mistakes, this is my first post.

Comment: Use a [`list`](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists)

Comment: Sidenote: your condition should have two `=` signs, not one, and you're missing the colon at the end of the line: `if c[n] == 0:`

Comment: If `c1` up to `c9` is in a library that you can't modify (highly doubtful), you may use `eval('c'+str(n))`.

Comment: Any time you think you need numbered variables you should be using a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you are definitely looking for lists:

```
c = []
c.append(0)   # access this using c[0]
c.append(0)   # access this using c[1]
...

# Alternatively fill the list from start
c = [0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1]

...

if c[n] == 0:
    p[n] = "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible, but I don't recommend it.

You can use `getattr(object_or_module_variables_are_in, 'a' + str(number))`

However, using `getattr` is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong.